# Oracle 12c Identity column with Eclipselink

Tags: java, oracle, eclipselink, oracle12c

I have a column defined as `MSG_ID NUMBER(24, 0) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY NOT NULL` in Oracle 12c database. I'm trying to insert  multiple records into its table using Eclipselink 2.6.2

Here's my entity class:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "MY_TABLE", catalog = "", schema = "MYSCHEMA")
    @XmlRootElement
    @PrimaryKey(validation = IdValidation.NULL)
    public class MyTable implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "MSG_ID")
        private Long msgId;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "MSG")
        private String msg;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "SENDER")
        private String sender;

        // Getters and setters...
    }
```

When I create a loop to insert multiple records in the table, I get the following Exception:

```
--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.v20151217-774c696): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Error Code: 942
Call: UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="SEQUENCE" sql="UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT + ? WHERE SEQ_NAME = ?")
```

And after that, an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An instance of a null PK has been incorrectly provided for this find operation` follows. as the ID is not generated by the table and there's no sequence to handle ID generation.

Is it a bug in Eclipselink or is it a mistake I made in my code?

Comment: I think you should use `GenerationType.IDENTITY` at least. Try to look here https://dnikiforov.wordpress.com/2015/02/14/oracle-12c-identity-and-popular-orms/

Comment: I tried it, but it produced the same exception, since AUTO lets Eclipse link choose the appropriate strategy. In this case it chooses the IDENTITY.

Comment: So you have to trace what SQL queries Eclipselink sends to Oracle. This should help you.

Comment: I updated the question with more information about the exception that contains the query sent requesting the sequence to generate the next ID.

Comment: As i can see EL chose `Table` strategy (cause of `UPDATE SEQUENCE SET SEQ_COUNT = SEQ_COUNT`). And what error do you see in case of `IDENTITY` strategy ?

Comment: `--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.v20151217-774c696): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

Error Code: 2289
Call: SELECT SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL
Query: ValueReadQuery(sql="SELECT SEQ_GEN_IDENTITY.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104891/discussion-between-agent5566-and-ahmad-hosny).

Comment: According to https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Oracle oracle did not support identity, so it is likely new and not built into EclipseLink's Oracle databasePlatform.  You can extend the platform yourself, or follow the instructions here https://dnikiforov.wordpress.com/2015/02/14/oracle-12c-identity-and-popular-orms/

Comment: please look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43279070/jpa-eclipselink-error-in-creating-tables