# JPA/EclipseLink Error in Creating Tables

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to create a table using EclipseLink. The java class being used is :-

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Submissions {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private Long Id;
 private String XID;
 private String Y;
 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 private Date uDate;
 private String level;
 private String state;

 public Submissions() {
 }

 //All Relevant getter and setter functions
}
```

The relevant persistence xml in question is as follows:-

```
<persistence-unit name="SubmissionIds">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.obp.selenium.DataObjects.OriginationSubmissions</class>
    <properties>

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="------" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="------" />

        <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
            value="database" />
        <!-- <property name="eclipselink.canonicalmodel.subpackage"
            value="originationSubmissions" /> -->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

We use the standard method is by implementing the EntityManagerFactory as :-

```
EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("SubmissionIds");
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
```

However I keep getting the following errors :-

> EL Warning]: 2017-04-07 14:04:53.768--ServerSession(1650327539)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.3.v20160428-59c81c5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
>
> Error Code: 904
>   Call: CREATE TABLE SUBMISSIONS (ID NUMBER(19) NOT NULL, XID VARCHAR2(255) NULL, Y VARCHAR2(255) NULL, LEVEL VARCHAR2(255) NULL, STATE VARCHAR2(255) NULL, UDATE DATE NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))
>   Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="CREATE TABLE SUBMISSIONS (ID NUMBER(19) NOT NULL, XID VARCHAR2(255) NULL, Y VARCHAR2(255) NULL, LEVEL VARCHAR2(255) NULL, STATE VARCHAR2(255) NULL, UDATE DATE NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))")

Comment: In your `persistence.xml`  there is not persistence unit called `"Trainstops"` which is you're trying to instantiate here: `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Trainstops")`. The persistence unit is called  `SubmissionIds` and the entity this PU maps is called `OriginationSubmissions` not `Submissions`. You should check both persistence unit name and class name are the right ones.

Comment: "LEVEL" is a reserved word and cannot be used as a column name.  Add the column annotation to your level attribute and name it something else in the table for this to work, or just give the attribute a different name.

Comment: @dic19 - Changed the entity name from TrainStops to SubmissionIds. Still the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avtually Eclipse reported a bug that rises when there is a reserved word usage you can fine here :
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=260637.

the problem comes from using a reserved word I dont actually know your DBMS, if it is Mysql your attributs
**XID** and **LEVEL**
 is a reserved word. you can find mysql reserved word here : 
 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html.

You can also se from the sql code used to build your tables that there is a column name update of type DATE

> UDATE DATE NULL

So to my opinion, you also need watch your attribut name on uDate

Answer (score 0):

The problem lay in the LEVEL named Field. @Chris has suggested the correct answer in the comment. **"LEVEL" is a reserved word and cannot be used as a column name. Add the column annotation to your level attribute and name it something else in the table for this to work, or just give the attribute a different name.**

Changing the field name worked easily.

Comment: Well it actually CAN be used as a column name, but you need to quote it. Other JPA providers do that for you, but seems yours doesn't

Comment: @Neil yes you are correct. But isn't it better if we steer away from using reserved words?

Comment: It is better that the user of software should not be imposed on by the persistence provider ... IMHO

Comment: I just wanted to say that I've used reserved words as column names (i.e.: "status") or table names (i.e.: "user") with both EclipseLink and Hibernate with no problems at all. If it makes any difference as a common practice I always use `@Column` annotation on fields specifying the column name there, even if it matches the Field name.

Answer (score 0):

This is very often due to the use of keywords as a column or table name.

For columns you can use **@Column(name = "new_name_with_keywords")**